# Error with styled component in view of ELM app

Tags: elm

cant understand how to use imported styled component in View module. here is the component itself:

```
module Logo exposing (logo)

import Css exposing (..)
import Html
import Html.Styled exposing (..)
import Html.Styled.Attributes exposing (css, src)

theme : { secondary : Color, primary : Color }
theme =
    { primary = hex "55af6a"
    , secondary = rgb 250 240 230
    }

logo : Html msg
logo =
  img
    [ src "logo.png"
    , css
        [ display inlineBlock
        , padding (px 20)
        , border3 (px 5) solid (rgb 120 120 120)
        , hover
            [ borderColor theme.primary
            , borderRadius (px 10)
            ]
        ]
    ]
    []
```

and here is where I want to use it:

```
view : Model -> Html Msg
view model =
  div [] [
    div [] [
      div [] [
        button
          [ onClick { operation = "INCREMENT", data = "Already clicked!" } ]
          [ text model.title ]
      ],
      div [] [
        logo
      ]
    ]
  ]
```

the error ELM shows me after compile is "Function `div` is expecting the 2nd argument to be:
List (Html msg)
But it is:
List (Html.Styled.Html msg)"

how can I use styled component in other components ? and what is the problem ?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

It looks like you are using the [`rtfeldman/elm-css`](http://package.elm-lang.org/packages/rtfeldman/elm-css/13.1.1) package for [`Html.Styled`](http://package.elm-lang.org/packages/rtfeldman/elm-css/13.1.1/Html-Styled) in the first block of code.

In the second block of code it sounds like you are using the standard [`elm-lang/html`](http://package.elm-lang.org/packages/elm-lang/html/2.0.0/Html) package.

It can become confusing to mix the two packages because they have many types and functions with identical names. However, the author of the `Html.Styled` package offers functions to convert between the two:

> You can convert from this to the normal `Html` type from `elm-lang/html` (which is a type alias for `VirtualDom.Node`) by using [`Html.Styled.toUnstyled`](http://package.elm-lang.org/packages/rtfeldman/elm-css/13.1.1/Html-Styled#toUnstyled).
>
> You can convert the other way using [`Html.Styled.fromUnstyled`](http://package.elm-lang.org/packages/rtfeldman/elm-css/13.1.1/Html-Styled#fromUnstyled).

I think in your case, the answer is this:

```elm
div [] [
    Html.Styled.toUnstyled logo
]
```